# Using Microsoft word for translation

Tags: microsoft-word, translation

I have thousands of pages translated into English.

The translations look like this:

- Word document 1:

```
Ti amo, un soldo,

ti amo, in aria,

ti amo, se viene testa

vuol dire che basta:

lasciamoci.

Ti amo, io sono,

ti amo, in fondo un uomo

che non ha freddo nel cuore,

nel letto comando io.
```

- Word document 2:

```
I love you,in my dream

I love you, in the air

i love you..............head

it means it's over:

let's split up.

i love you ,i m

acctually a man

who hasnt a cold heart

in bed i command
```

---

And I need the translations to look like this:

Word document 3:

```
I love you,in my dream

Ti amo, un soldo,

I love you, in the air

ti amo, in aria,

i love you..............head

ti amo, se viene testa

it means it's over:

vuol dire che basta:

let's split up.

lasciamoci.

i love you ,i m

Ti amo, io sono,

acctually a man

ti amo, in fondo un uomo

who hasnt a cold heart

che non ha freddo nel cuore,

in bed i command

nel letto comando io.
```

How can I do that? I don't have the time to do it manually, because there are millions of sentences. I need a program that does it directly.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This kind of thing looks like it should be very doable a number of different ways.  Unfortunately, the site isn't intended to be a free coding service.  People will help with a specific problem, though, if you attempt it yourself and get stuck.  But include what you've tried and what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried searching for it in the word help window (once you open a document), but nothing solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save both files as text (not as Word files), then copy and paste the following
lines into a file called, for example, `merge.bat`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set f1=1.txt
set f2=2.txt
set outfile=mix.txt
type nul>%outfile%
<%f2% (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (%f1%) do (
        set /p line=
        IF [%%a] == [] IF [!line!] == [] goto next
        echo %%a >>%outfile%
        echo !line! >>%outfile%
:next
        echo. >>%outfile%
    )
)
```

Ensure that both input files and the `.bat` file are in the same folder.
Start a Command Prompt (cmd), navigate to that folder, then execute the
`.bat` file.
The result will be in the file `mix.txt`.
You may change the names of the input and output files in the script as required.

Comment: Is there another way to do it? I have trouble with the text files because they don't recognize chinese and japanese.

Comment: Try to enter in CMD the command `chcp 65001` for UTF-8 before running the `.bat` file, and open the result file with Notepad++ and set the Encoding to UTF-8.